# Price changes when using decimal data type

Tags: mysql, decimal, sqldatatypes

I have a column with the data type `decimal` setup as so..

```
`cost` decimal(4,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
```

However when I input a price, say 100.00, next time I look at it it says `99.99`.

Why is this? I thought `4,2` allowed 4 chars before the decimal & 2 after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4 is the precision (total number of digits), 2 is the scale (decimal places).

In your case you want 6,2.

Answer (score 1):

A `DECIMAL(M,D)` column permits at most **M - D** digits to the left of the decimal point.

**M** is the maximum number of digits (the precision).

Answer (score 1):

decimal [ (p[ ,s] )] and numeric[ (p[ ,s] )]
Fixed precision and scale numbers. When maximum precision is used, valid values are from - 10^38 +1 through 10^38 - 1. The ISO synonyms for decimal are dec and dec(p, s). numeric is functionally equivalent to decimal.

BOTTOM LINE:
you should try and make it 6,2.

6 as in total 6 digits, 2 as in 2 digits after the point.